# How to target sub menu active level?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

http://misha.pixelworklab.com/mercedes-sl/

You will see the "MERCEDES" tab in the current state which is correct but I need to have the submenu have a different current state as it looks terrible.. Have tried every selector and seem to be missing something.. THANKS!

Have tried `.current-menu-item > a` but cannot get the selector for the sub element.

[image]

Comment: Have tried ".current-menu-item > a" but cannot get the selector for the sub element.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's built in **CSS Inspector Tools** can help you find the selector(s) you need to customize the `hover` active state appearance.

Here is your **CSS Active State Selector** for hovering navigation links:

```css
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu>li:hover>a span.wpmega-link-title,#megaMenu ul.megaMenu>li:hover>span.um-anchoremulator span.wpmega-link-title,#megaMenu ul.megaMenu>li>a:hover span.wpmega-link-title,#megaMenu ul.megaMenu>li>span.um-anchoremulator:hover span.wpmega-link-title,#megaMenu ul.megaMenu>li.megaHover>a span.wpmega-link-title,#megaMenu ul.megaMenu>li.megaHover>span.um-anchoremulator span.wpmega-link-title
```

Since it's cRaZy LoNg and ubber complex, I'll explain how I arrived at this selector **Step-by-Step**, with latest version of Firefox on PC:

**1.)** Right-click the `MERCEDES KITS` nav link and choose **Inspect Element(Q)** from the context menu.
[image]

**2.)** You'll be on the `span` tag. Hovering will change the text color to **`red`**, as defined by the CSS styles.
[image]

**3.)** Click the drop-down arrow on the `span` CSS selector and force it to **always** be in `:hover` state.
[image]

**4.)** Press the **Style Button** located at the bottom right so it's active. When active, that button turns blue.
[image]

**5.)** At top of the **CSS Rules Panel**, you'll see the selector(s) responsible for making the text `red`.
[image]

**6.)** In this same section, you have access to the **CSS Stylesheet** and **Line Number** for these selectors:
[image]

**7.)** Line Number 169 provides the **`hover` active state appearance** for all navigation anchors:

```css
/* Top Level Items Title - Hover */
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li:hover > a span.wpmega-link-title,
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li:hover > span.um-anchoremulator span.wpmega-link-title,
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li > a:hover span.wpmega-link-title,
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li > span.um-anchoremulator:hover span.wpmega-link-title,
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li.megaHover > a span.wpmega-link-title,
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li.megaHover > span.um-anchoremulator span.wpmega-link-title {
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #ffffff;
  color: red !important;
}
```

**8.)** You can ***dynamically edit the CSS*** in Firefox **CSS Rule Panel** directly.
Example `hover` color change is to use: **`color: yellow !important;`** for **Step 5** above:
[image]

**9.)** TIP: See the **HTML Panel**, 2nd icon from bottom left, to **view other** `classname` and `id` elements.
[image]

Comment: I understand all this of this and thanks for the help. However, this is not helping me to target my sub-menu. Only the toplevel one. No matter what I do I cannot get a differnt active state for my submenu than my top level one. (see screenshot)

Comment: The method I've describe shows you how to get any classname or id to use as your target, whether it's a top-level or sub-menu item. Having said that, please explain what is it that you want to accomplish or expect to happen. Also clarify what part of the sub-menu your after (entire sub or just a automobile).

Comment: [**jsFiddle MERCEDES KITS Sub-Menu Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4GDxw/show/) Remove `/show/` from address bar to access jsFiddle edit page.  In this jsFiddle example, I used the process in my answer to learn what selectors I can use to then modify the sub-menu. To see the sub-menu at any time **without** hoovering over it, use `display:block` as shown in the last photo of my answer for that sub-menu. You'll need to do it again after hoovering again.

Answer (score 0):

You could target the sub menu with `ul.sub-menu` and its child selectors.

`ul.sub-menu`
`ul.sub-menu li`
`ul.sub-menu li:first-child a`
`ul.sub-menu li a`
`ul.sub-menu li:last-child a`

Things like that.